# Pick Matrix Cells with Highest Sum

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Suppose I have a 6x4 matrix. Each cell has a value from 0 to 100 in it.

How can I select the four cells that have the highest sums given that only one cell can be selected per column and once a row has a cell selected, it cannot be selected again?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

6x4 is pretty small.

I would divide into four 6x1 rows and take two pairs of two rows to make two 6x6 sum matrix. 
Pick two cells, `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` one from each sum matrix, which have highest sum where column and row indices of two cells are not equal, meaning `x1,x2,y1,y2` are unique.